# SQL SET DEFAULT not working in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, default, alter-table, alter-column

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [DEFAULT clause in ALTER TABLE statement resulting in syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10440990/default-clause-in-alter-table-statement-resulting-in-syntax-error)

I am trying to execute the following statement using a SQL query within MS Access;

```
ALTER TABLE [table] ALTER COLUMN [column] SET DEFAULT 'default value'
```

However, I get a dialog displaying the error `Syntax error in ALTER TABLE statement.`

And when I click OK it highlights the word `DEFAULT`. I also tried the following statement;

```
ALTER TABLE [table]
ADD CONSTRAINT [Default] DEFAULT 'default value' FOR [column]
```

And I get another error `Syntax error in CONSTRAINT clause.`

What is the correct syntax for setting a default value in MS Access?  The db file is Access 2003 format.

Comment: The second one is standard SQL, but I don't believe that it's supported in Access. See [`ALTER TABLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb177883(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10440990/default-clause-in-alter-table-statement-resulting-in-syntax-error. It can't be done using SQL. I have voted to close this question.

Comment: That previous question was about an Access 97 db.  And since much of Access DDL capability (including `DEFAULT`) was not introduced until Jet 4 (Access 2000), the previous question applies here only if Steztric is also using Access 97 format as his db file.

Comment: @Steztric What Access version is your db file?

Comment: @shahkalpesh: Not to be closed, since this one has a better answerby Hansup, in my view. By the way, there's is no way voting *against* a close ?!

Comment: @HansUp Access 2003 I believe, although I am opening it in Access 2010 without upgrading (it may mess up our business logic, who knows?)

Comment: @iDevlop: Right. There isn't a way to mark it for not closing it. am modifying the question add Access 2003 tag to it.

Comment: Please leave this tagged as ms-access because it applies across multiple Access versions.  I included Access 2003 in the body of the question.

Comment: @HansUp if your reopening was justified, please remove the link to the duplicate, otherwise please re-close the Question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Support for `DEFAULT` was included in Access DDL with Jet 4 (Access 2000).  However it can only be used in DDL executed from an ADO connection.

This worked with Access 2007.

```
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "ALTER TABLE MyTable " & _
    "ALTER COLUMN field2 SET DEFAULT ""foo"";"
```

Note if your db file is Access 97 or earlier, you won't be able to set a field `DEFAULT` value from DDL.

Comment: Thank you @HansUp, this is what I was looking for. In fact the reason I am executing SQL from within Access is as a sandpit area to ensure I was writing the correct ODB query to do this in code.

Comment: You're welcome.  I'm unsure whether that ALTER TABLE will work from an ODBC connection.  If it does not, use an OleDb connection instead because it will work then.

Comment: I already post this in another thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13605663/how-to-add-a-boolean-column-to-ms-access-via-sql-in-vb-net/13606223#comment55764481_13606223). I just discovered that if you do an ALTER TABLE  ADD for a BIT / YESNO column via a SQL window in Access (haven't tried through ADO but I suspect it will act the same way), for existing rows, it won't apply the DEFAULT supplied value if you set it to `TRUE`, but sets it to 0. New ones will, though. Thanks, MS!

Answer (score 0):

It seems, there would be `Constraint` issue with your column. Although following DDL statement is the correct way.

```
ALTER TABLE Persons ALTER COLUMN City SET DEFAULT 'SANDNES'
```

[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_default.asp)