# Change default value of field through vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to change the default value of a field I just added through VBA. I have this line of code below that I added in to do so but for some reason it is saying the item is not in the collection and I am really confused as to why. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
AddColumn = "ALTER TABLE ShouldImportMetricsIDsTable " & _
"ADD COLUMN [ImportStatus] TEXT"

db.Execute AddColumn

CurrentDb.TableDefs("ShouldImportMetricsIDs").Fields("ImportStatus").DefaultValue = "No"
```

I have also included the line that adds the field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just pointed to different tables in `ALTER TABLE` you referenced `ShouldImportMetricsIDsTable` and in VBA code `ShouldImportMetricsIDs`.

P.S. `DefaultValue` property is build in so you can easily set its value

```
CurrentDb.TableDefs("ShouldImportMetricsIDsTable").Fields("ImportStatus").DefaultValue = "No"
```

but some other field properties are odd so you have to use constructions like that:

```
Dim p As Property
Set p = CurrentDb.TableDefs("ShouldImportMetricsIDsTable").Fields("ImportStatus").CreateProperty("DefaultValue", dbText, "No")
CurrentDb.TableDefs("ShouldImportMetricsIDsTable").Fields("ImportStatus").Properties.Append (p)
```

Comment: Thank you! This did change the default property but this table is a copy of another so there are already records in it. How would I get all the existing records to be no as well?

Comment: Execute UPDATE query with `WHERE [ImportStatus] is null` or `WHERE [ImportStatus]=''`

Answer (score 1):

I think you can add the default value to the `ALTER TABLE` expression:

```
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "ALTER TABLE ShouldImportMetricsIDsTable " & _
"ADD COLUMN [ImportStatus] TEXT" & _
"DEFAULT ""No"";"
```

I'm basing my answer off this question: [SQL SET DEFAULT not working in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057085/sql-set-default-not-working-in-ms-access)

EDIT: Looking at the answer from HansUp in that link, I edited the answer above to reflect the syntax he uses there. I hope this works for you.

Comment: It says that there is a syntax error in the field definition when I try to run that...

Comment: The SQL needs to include a space between TEXT and DEFAULT.