# Database Access Mdb how to set a default value to existing column via SQL

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, asp-classic

I have a 12 years old `mdb` database and I was asked to add a new column to a table and set to a default value of "1".

My knowledge of `asp`/`mdb` is close to zero. I also have no Access or similar softwares.

I tried with:

```
 ALTER TABLE Members ADD COLUMN Privacy Double Default 1
```

but generates error:

> Error: An action query cannot be used as a row source.

Then I tried with:

```
 ALTER TABLE Members MODIFY COLUMN Privacy VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Yes';
```

but this also triggers another error:

> Microsoft JET Database Engine error '80040e14'

How can I set an existing column to a default value?

Should I use an offline tool? If so which one?

**Note:** I also used an online tool to create the new column but it has no option to set a default value.

So I can either create the new column with the tool and set a default value with SQL, or do the creation of the column with the default value still with SQL.

Comment: have you tried [this syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057085/sql-set-default-not-working-in-ms-access)?

Comment: @luk2302 yes I tried but I get the same error "Error: An action query cannot be used as a row source."

Comment: The above comment suggests that you are setting a recordset to the result of the query, just execute it.

Comment: just a stupid question: can't you edit the table via design view? O_O

Comment: @krish from the above " I also have no Access or similar softwares.)"

Comment: @Fionnuala: I run SQL commands from an old online tool called "Table Editor" that reads the mdb file, is similar to PHPMyAdmin but very simple and basic. I just run the above query with no results... should I create specific ASP files and run them?

Comment: Try it, but be careful and use a copy of the mdb make sure you use the right connection. I know nothing about Table Editor.

Comment: There's a free tool called WinSql lite which you can use to edit an mdb file via an odbc connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved using [AxBase](http://sourceforge.net/projects/axbase/) from [SourceForge.net](http://sourceforge.net).

I could properly open the *.mdb database and run the above SQL commands and they worked perfectly:

```
 ALTER TABLE Members ALTER COLUMN Privacy SET DEFAULT 1
```

Answer (score -1):

hi your access database is may be in office 2003 or office xp.
You can try to enable sql syntax and then try to run your query.

Tools -> Options -> Tables/Queries -> (At the bottom right:) Sql Server Compatible Syntax - turn option on for this database.

```
ALTER TABLE Members ADD COLUMN Privacy number Default 1
```

Comment: You can run such statements from VBA, but not from the query design window. Changing to Sql Server Compatible Syntax may ruin a dozen things. Furthermore, the OP is using asp classic.